# Dynamically size jqGrid Add/Edit Form fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I have a jqGrid that has multiple select boxes and text fields.  I would like all of the form fields to be the same length.  I would like all of the form fields to be the size of the widest select box or text field.  Is there a way that I can do this?

Thanks for all of your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [afterShowForm](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:form_editing#events) event to get the width of the widest select box and to set the width of all selects to the value.

The [demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/DynamicFormWidth.htm) change the standard Edit/Add form from

[image]

to

[image]

The corresponding code:

```
var resizeSelectWidth = function ($form) {
        var maxWidth = 0, newMaxWidth = 0, i,
            $selects = $form.find('tr.FormData > td.DataTD > select.FormElement'),
            cn = $selects.length;

        // calculate the max width of selects
        for (i = 0; i < cn; i += 1) {
            maxWidth = Math.max(maxWidth, $($selects[i]).width());
        }
        maxWidth += 2; // increase width to improve visibility

        // change the width of selects to the max width
        for (i = 0; i < cn; i += 1) {
            $($selects[i]).width(maxWidth);
            newMaxWidth = Math.max(maxWidth, $($selects[i]).width());
        }
    };

...
$("#list").jqGrid('navGrid', '#pager', {del: true},
    {afterShowForm: resizeSelectWidth},
    {afterShowForm: resizeSelectWidth});
```